# If two domains measure the same thing how to approach a cluster analysis?

Tags: clustering, factor-analysis

I would like to perform a cluster analysis on my sample with a set of variables categorized in several domains. This is just fine but my problem is that two domains (one consisting of four and one of five variables) measure the same thing (just in a different way). As my aim is to profile the people in the sample with the cluster analysis I should only be considering one of the two domains measuring the same thing. Before excluding one preferring another is there a formal way to demonstrate that my population behaves similarly to the questions of both domains? If I can prove that they answer similarly there would be no problem to pick one or the other!

Comment: Hi David, can you share a representative data table to make it easier to conceptualise what type of variables you are looking at? I think the question as it stands is a bit too abstract and may not get much attention.

Answer (score 0):

Choose an appropriate weight.
E.g. put half as much weight on each of them as you would normally do.
Note that you also need to weight each variable individually. You don't want to lose an important feature just because it is measured on a smaller scale, and not redundant in four variables.

It's an art - there isn't a one-size-fits-all scheme.